# Ubuntu 16.04/Unity: How do I create a a launcher shortcut for a Wine app that is --not-- also in my desktop?

Tags: unity, 16.04, wine, launcher

so I installed foobar2000 and it created a desktop icon for me. I can pinned foobar2000 into launcher but once I delete the desktop icon, the launcher shortcut also disappears.

I just want to delete/hide the desktop shortcut while retaining launcher shortcut.

Thanks

**edit1:** sample .desktop file that works.

```
chiyo@chiyo:~$ cat .local/share/applications/dBpoweramp\ CD\ Ripper.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Name=dBpoweramp CD Ripper
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/chiyo/.wine" wine C:\\\\Program\\ Files\\ \\(x86\\)\\\\dBpoweramp\\\\CDGrab.exe 
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Path=/home/chiyo/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files (x86)/dBpoweramp/
Icon=D8E2_CDGrab.0
```

**edit2:** I moved the .desktop file from /home/chiyo/Desktop to /home/chiyo/.local/share/applications. I restarted by PC and when Ubuntu came back, there are no new launcher shortcuts.

Comment: You would place the .desktop in ~/.local/share/applications, then pin it to the launcher.

Comment: @doug that's what I did. but it seems I cannot delete the desktop shortcut while retaining the launcher shortcut. I just want to delete/hide the desktop shortcut while retaining launcher shortcut.

Comment: Maybe post the contents of the provided .desktop. Also I said put That .desktop in ~/.local/share/applications, Then pin to launcher. Here I have a couple of .desktops for foobar, the basic one that just opens foobar is in the above location & works fine in the unity launcher

Comment: it works now. very new to Ubuntu and didn't understood it at first. Thanks! :)